# reading images from memory card ANDROID

Tags: android

```
int image[] = {R.drawable.d002_p001,R.drawable.d002_p002,R.drawable.d002_p003,
                   R.drawable.d002_p004,R.drawable.d002_p005,R.drawable.d002_p006};
showPhoto(imCurrentPhotoIndex);


    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("photo_index", imCurrentPhotoIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        imCurrentPhotoIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("photo_index");
        showPhoto(imCurrentPhotoIndex);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void showPhoto(int photoIndex) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        // imageView.setImageResource(imPhotoIds[photoIndex]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imPhotoIds[photoIndex]);

    }
```

above code is used to read and display images from drawable folder. 
I want read images from a folder in memory card; what i should do?

Comment: You should go to this link http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card you can do this either by usign content resolver or by getting abosolute path using getExternalStorageDirectory

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the path of images. Assuming you have only images in your folder.

```
    ArrayList<String> thumb = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] listFile; 

    public void getFromSdcard()
    {
    File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"foldername");

        if (file.isDirectory())
        { 
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {
               thumb.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }
}
```

Now you can use the path of the images in arraylist thumb.

Remember to add the read permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To set it to image view

```
 ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
 Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumb.get(photoIndex).toString); // get the file and decode
 image.setImageBitmap(b);
```